# Riddle: You made me what I am today - What am I?

Tags: riddle, rhyme, poetry

> You made me what I am today
>   And that is why I'll never stray
>   You took me in, to your very core
>   And built me up to something more.
>
> On warmer days, unseen I'll stay
>   For you're happy alone anyway
>   But when day gives way to colder night
>   To see me, just head to the light
>
> As you let out that lonesome sigh,
>   Look toward the corner of your eye
>   Against the darkness, there I'll be
>   With your sweet lips caressing me
>
> And so, too, love, I'll come to you
>   On gloomy days, when no sun shines through
>   But should I fade, and leave only strife
>   Recall your sweet sigh gives me new life.
>
> Remember, even if this fleeting love
>   Should drift away to clouds above,
>   And I seem to pass on before my time
>   We'll meet again, if in another clime.
>
> For what we deem death is but change of form,
>   So forevermore, I'll keep you warm.
>   But as I drift up through cold, dark sky
>   I'll ask you once:
>   What am I?

Comment: =_= Can't tell if celestial, meteorological, or biological.

Comment: It starts as part of the third category, then becomes two things (at least) in the second.

Answer (score 4):

the answer maybe:

> water, moisture, vapor

You made me what I am today
And that is why I'll never stray
You took me in, to your very core
And built me up to something more.

> we are made up of water, and we take water in our core

On warmer days, unseen I'll stay
For you're happy alone anyway
But when day gives way to colder night
To see me, just head to the light

> in hot days water stays as vapor so unseen, but when it gets cold at night look at street lamps to see it rain or snow

As you let out that lonesome sigh,
Look toward the corner of your eye
Against the darkness, there I'll be
With your sweet lips caressing me

> you breath out vapor, and shed tears and a glass of water for the thirst

And so, too, love, I'll come to you
On gloomy days, when no sun shines through
But should I fade, and leave only strife
Recall your sweet sigh gives me new life.

> ? clouds

Remember, even if this fleeting love
Should drift away to clouds above,
And I seem to pass on before my time
We'll meet again, if in another clime.

> water evaporates and comes back in another form maybe at another location

For what we deem death is but change of form,
So forevermore, I'll keep you warm.
But as I drift up through cold, dark sky
I'll ask you once:
What am I?

> lifecycle of water, and moist keeps the climate warm

Comment: I like the corner of the eye interpreted as a tear! However, I wasn't thinking that deeply.  I just meant to emphasize visibility.  Actually, your whole take on that stanza is a little in depth, and the conclusion's broader than the answer.
HOWEVER, even with that said, water's only one of the constituents of what I actually meant to be the answer.  Nice work!  Most of it you were able to explain, but again, there's a key constituent to the _real_ answer that might explain some things more concretely.

Comment: I don't know; I didn't include any of that in this one.

Answer (score 4):

> Breath

You made me what I am today
 And that is why I'll never stray
 You took me in, to your very core
 And built me up to something more.

> You exhale to make a breath after taking it in to your very core.

On warmer days, unseen I'll stay
 For you're happy alone anyway
 But when day gives way to colder night
 To see me, just head to the light

> On cold days you see your breath, especially under a light like a street lamp.

As you let out that lonesome sigh,
 Look toward the corner of your eye
 Against the darkness, there I'll be
 With your sweet lips caressing me

> A white vapour against the darkness.  Exhale through the mouth and your lips caress your breath.

And so, too, love, I'll come to you
 On gloomy days, when no sun shines through
 But should I fade, and leave only strife
 Recall your sweet sigh gives me new life.

> On particularly 'gloomy', low temperature, high humidity days you'll see your breath.

Remember, even if this fleeting love
 Should drift away to clouds above,
 And I seem to pass on before my time
 We'll meet again, if in another clime.

> Your breath is vapour like a cloud and it drifts away as you exhale.  Climate effects how visible your breath is.

For what we deem death is but change of form,
 So forevermore, I'll keep you warm.
 But as I drift up through cold, dark sky
 I'll ask you once:
 What am I?

> You can warm your hands etc. with your breath.

Answer (score 2):

Answer:

> Water vapour / Moisture (exhaled)

You made me what I am today
You took me in, to your very core
And built me up to something more.

> You breathed in oxygen into the lungs and exhaled water vapour (hydrogen + oxygen)

On warmer days, unseen I'll stay
For you're happy alone anyway
But when day gives way to colder night
To see me, just head to the light

> Exhaled moisture can be seen only during winter, provided there is sufficient light of course

As you let out that lonesome sigh,
Look toward the corner of your eye
Against the darkness, there I'll be

> When you're lonesome, your become teary-eyed?

With your sweet lips caressing me

> Not clear: Moisture on lips?

And so, too, love, I'll come to you
On gloomy days, when no sun shines through

> The water vapor rises up and forms clouds, making for gloomy days

But should I fade, and leave only strife
Recall your sweet sigh gives me new life.

> Every sigh creates more of it

Remember, even if this fleeting love
Should drift away to clouds above,

> Same as above

And I seem to pass on before my time
We'll meet again, if in another clime.
For what we deem death is but change of form,

> A reference to the monsoon/winter that will follow, when it will rain/snow, i.e. the vapor changes to liquid or solid form

So forevermore, I'll keep you warm.

> Until then, it just adds to the humidity, making you feel warmer.

Comment: Maybe I shouldn't have been so specific about the corner of the eye; I just thought it fit better into the meter and rhyme than trying to work in "edge of your vision" or "periphery".  Likewise, the gloomy day thing was originally just to clarify that it doesn't necessarily need to be nighttime in order for it to be visible.

Answer (score 2):

You are:

> A wood fire in a fireplace, turning into smoke and ash

"Can't tell if celestial, meteorological, or biological"
"It starts as part of the third category (biological)"

> wood

"then becomes two things (at least) in the second."

> smoke and ash

You made me what I am today
And that is why I'll never stray
You took me in, to your very core
And built me up to something more

> I light wood brought and put inside my house's (core) fireplace

On warmer days, unseen I'll stay
For you're happy alone anyway
But when day gives way to colder night
To see me, just head to the light

> No need for fire in a fireplace on warmer days, but a need when it gets cold

As you let out that lonesome sigh,
Look toward the corner of your eye
Against the darkness, there I'll be
With your sweet lips caressing me

> I imagine a dark cabin with a lit fireplace, not sure about the lips caressing part..

And so, too, love, I'll come to you
On gloomy days, when no sun shines through
But should I fade, and leave only strife
Recall your sweet sigh gives me new life.

> Past the polar circles (where there is less sun, depending on the season) people light more fires to heat. Fires are easy to start in indoors fireplaces.

Remember, even if this fleeting love
Should drift away to clouds above,
And I seem to pass on before my time
We'll meet again, if in another clime.

> Wooden fireplaces turn into smoke and ash

For what we deem death is but change of form,
So forevermore, I'll keep you warm.
But as I drift up through cold, dark sky

> Smoke drifts up